# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets webkit

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, qtwebkit, yocto, qt5.2

I am new in **Qt** and **Yocto**. I used **Poky** toolchain to cross-compile **Qt5** on Ubuntu 12.04.LTS.

I installed and configure **Qt5** following [these instructions for Building Qt5 using yocto on Wandboard](http://wiki.wandboard.org/index.php/Building_Qt5_using_yocto_on_Wandboard).

```
/configure v -dont-process -opensource -confirm-license -device imx6 -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/poky/1.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi -sysroot /fsl-community-bsp/buildcoreimage/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabreauto -prefix ~/qt5arm -platform linux-g++ -shared -no-pch -no-rpath -pkg-config -no-accessibility -no-dbus -no-icu -no-directfb -evdev -no-fontconfig -no-opengl -opengl es2 -eglfs -no-glib -no-gtkstyle -no-iconv -system-libjpeg -no-kms -system-libpng -no-linuxfb -no-mitshm -no-nis -openssl -qt-pcre -release -no-sm -no-sql-db2 -no-sql-ibase -no-sql-mysql -no-sql-oci -no-sql-odbc -no-sql-psql -no-sql-sqlite -no-sql-sqlite2 -no-sql-tds -nomake tests -tslib -libudev -widgets -no-xcb -no-xcursor -no-xfixes -no-xinerama -no-xinput -no-xinput2 -no-xkb -no-xrandr -no-xrender -no-xshape -no-xsync -no-xvideo -system-zlib
```

When i tried to build my project with `qmake` I got the following error:

```
hmi_ph2$ /home/abc/qt5arm/bin/qmake
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets webkit
```

so I did

```
sudo apt-get upgrade libqt5webkit5-dev
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

in my `.pro` file:

```
QT += qml quick xml network widgets webkit webkitwidgets xmlpatterns multimedia multimediawidgets
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to link against `webkit`, not `webkitwidgets` : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwebkitwidgets-index.html

So in your case you have to remove `webkitwidgets` from the line QT += ....

**EDIT :** As pointed out by  [Laszlo Papp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2682142/laszlo-papp), the problem is not there. After looking at the `configure` option for Qt (from the 4.8 doc : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/configure-options.html), there is a `-webkit` option. I do not know if this option still exist for Qt5 as I couldn't find the full option list in Qt5 Doc (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/configure-options.html), but if you try `configure -help` you 'll see if it exist. If that is the case then it might be your missing piece.

Comment: This does not seem to be the issue because it is not an error to link against webkitwidgets (although it could be unnecessary), and the OP also seems to have issues with webkit.